# Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK: windows library v1.30.0 missing extension lib for VAD Engine Adapter

Tags: c#, sdk, detection, voice, speech

Running console app for speech recognition using Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK 1.30.0 causes the below error

#### C# code error message:

Unhandled exception. System.ApplicationException: Exception with an error code: 0x24 (SPXERR_EXTENSION_LIBRARY_NOT_FOUND)

#### Debug logs just before exception:

[553436]: 152ms SPX_DBG_TRACE_FUNCTION:  audio_stream_session.cpp:2834 CSpxAudioStreamSession::EnsureInitDetectionEngineAdapter
[553436]: 152ms SPX_DBG_TRACE_VERBOSE:  named_properties.h:477 ISpxNamedProperties::GetStringValue: this=0x000001F28008D498; name='IsVadModeOn'; value='true'
[553436]: 152ms SPX_DBG_TRACE_VERBOSE:  named_properties.h:477 ISpxPropertyBagImpl::SetStringValue: this=0x000001F28008D498; name='IsProcessingVAD'; value='true'
[553436]: 152ms SPX_DBG_TRACE_VERBOSE:  audio_stream_session.cpp:2915 [000001F28008D3B0]CSpxAudioStreamSession::InitKwsEngineAdapter ...
[553436]: 152ms SPX_DBG_TRACE_VERBOSE:  named_properties.h:477 ISpxNamedProperties::GetStringValue: this=0x000001F28008D498; name='IsVadModeOn'; value='true'
[553436]: 152ms SPX_TRACE_WARNING: resource_manager.cpp:127 Failed to create 'CSpxSdkVadEngineAdapter' as '279346415'. Are all required extension libraries loaded?
[553436]: 152ms SPX_THROW_HR_IF:  audio_stream_session.cpp:2970 (0x024) = 0x24
[553436]: 194ms SPX_TRACE_ERROR:  exception.cpp:123 About to throw Exception with an error code: 0x24 (SPXERR_EXTENSION_LIBRARY_NOT_FOUND)

#### Expected behaviour:

VAD Engine Adapter included in Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK and available for usage.

#### Tried to:

- search the internet for running Voice Activity Detection in Microsoft Cognitive Services Speech SDK and Microsoft Audio Stack, but found no clear instruction how to do it.
- find similar issue with a solution. Although there are some question regarding "Exception with an error code: 0x24 (SPXERR_EXTENSION_LIBRARY_NOT_FOUND)", but none is related to lack of VAD Engine Adapter.

Comment: Did you got this error by running some of the samples in https://github.com/Azure-Samples/cognitive-services-speech-sdk or did you enable the VAD somehow in the application code? Currently VAD extension has not been released publicly.